# Why is my PowerShell function's parameter showing up as empty/blank?

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

On a whim, in order to learn PowerShell, which I know I'm woefully behind on, I decided to write a super simple script to use MSBuild to clean a bunch of solutions in code, then build them with a certain set of arguments. Here's the script:

```
$sourceDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$cleanArgs = '/t:clean /verbosity:q /nologo /P:Configuration=Debug'
$buildArgs = '/verbosity:q /nologo /P:Platform="Any CPU";Configuration=Debug'
$solutions = @("asdf.sln","qwer.sln","zxcv.sln","yuio.sln","hjkl.sln","nm.sln")

function buildWithArgs([string[]]$solutionsToBuild = @(), [string]$args = 'default')
{
    Write-Host args: $args
    foreach($sln in $solutionsToBuild)
    {
        & $env:WINDIR\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "$sourceDir\$sln $args" | Out-Default
    }
}

buildWithArgs $solutions $buildArgs
buildWithArgs $solutions $cleanArgs
```

Now, my problem is that the function "buildWithArgs" doesn't respect the $args parameter, which is always empty when I run or debug the script, no matter what I pass in. The $solutionsToBuild parameter works flawlessly, however. Do I have improper syntax? Even if it were the case that my $cleanArgs string was somehow improperly formatted or not escaped, I can't even make the function work with simple strings like "asdf", as $args is always empty when I run it. Thanks for any help you can provide to what is assuredly some small, silly error!

Comment: Things I have tried: surrounding MSBuild's args with quotes, changing $cleanArgs' quotes from double (with escaping around "Any CPU") to single quotes, changing the '&' command to Invoke-Item and Invoke-Expression. I should note that if I refer to the global variables $cleanArgs or $buildArgs, instead of a function parameter, it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `$args` is a special, built-in parameter in PowerShell, which represents all the arguments to a function.  One of the side-effects to this is you can't see its value in the ISE debugger.  Try changing its name to `MSBuildArgs`.

Make sure you define, `buildArgs` and `cleanArgs` as arrays.  You're defining them as one single string.  You do this so you can use PowerShell's splat operator (`@` instead of `$` when referencing a variable), which sends each argument in an array as a parameter to a command.

Lastly, you don't need to quote parameters that are stored in variables.  PowerShell will do any quoting for you.

After making these changes, you'll have something like this:

```
$sourceDir = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition -Parent
$cleanArgs = @('/t:clean','/verbosity:q','/nologo','/P:Configuration=Debug')
$buildArgs = @('/verbosity:q','/nologo','/P:Platform="Any CPU";Configuration=Debug')
$solutions = @("asdf.sln","qwer.sln","zxcv.sln","yuio.sln","hjkl.sln","nm.sln")

function buildWithArgs([string[]]$solutionsToBuild = @(), [string[]]$MSBuildArgs= 'default')
{
    Write-Host args: $args
    foreach($sln in $solutionsToBuild)
    {
        $msbuildPath = Join-Path $env:WINDIR Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe -Resolve
        & $msbuildPath (Join-Path $sourceDir $sln -Resolve) @MSBuildArgs | `
            Out-Default
    }
}

buildWithArgs $solutions $buildArgs
buildWithArgs $solutions $cleanArgs
```

Comment: Mostly correct! unfortunately, the parameter including the space ('/P:Platform="Any CPU";Configuration=Debug') causes MSBuild to explode, as it thinks that the text after the space is a new parameter. Sad! But I can try to figure that out...

Answer (score 2):

`$args` is a [special automatic variable](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html) in powershell functions.  It contains an array of parameters which are not otherwise bound to the declared parameters of the function.  By plain bad luck/inexperience, you happened to name one of your declared parameters the same, which will cause issues.

If you rename your parameter to something else, say `$BuildArgs`, it should be properly bound.

Note, however, that your current code will execute msbuild with a single parameter consisting of the solution path and args together.  It is not the syntax to invoke msbuild with *multiple* arguments.  If this causes issues for you I would suggest opening another question or searching online for that particular issue, just so this question does not get too big.